# Deleting row from Database via Combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a combobox which is looking into my Database and showing me the names of the users, I also want to look at the the dID besides that, this task I am finding difficult to achieve. I have two tables, so I presume that I have to repeat this SQL statement. Please look into this code !

All in all what I want to achieve is to Just to delete the user from the database! the members personal info form table_1 and the info about members paid amount and year dID form the table_2 ! One delete command deletes one row for members info in table_1 & table_2.

Any other methods or ideas welcome !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CemiyetAidatSistem
{
    public partial class DeleteUser : Form
    {
        String conStr ="My connection string";
        public UyeSil()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        private void UserDelete_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FullName FROM Members";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "Members");
            cmbUyeSil.DataSource = ds.Tables["Members"];
            cmbUyeSil.DisplayMember = "DistinctID";
            cmbUyeSil.ValueMember = "FullName";

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Members WHERE ID = '" + cmbUyeSil.SelectedValue + "'";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(" Member with dID \"" + cmbUyeSil.SelectedValue + "\"is deleted");

        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: just as aside, I never delete users or products or anything that might be hooked up with reports, I simply use a column `active` and set it to `false` when the admin wants to delete anything... plus I save a log of the action and `entity_id` that was performed so i can always track the issue...

Comment: Can you please give information about the structure of the tables?

Comment: @balexandre: you make an excellent point here! Physically deleting users from a system destroys any hope of traceability ...

Comment: Melanie table_1 has ID, dID, Name Address, Telephone, Email. table_2 has ID, dID, Year, and Amount !!! –

Answer (score 1):

If you have [cascading delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on then when you delete the user this will cause the row(s) in table 2 to also be deleted

Comment: In order to use a cascade delete there has to be a relationship between the 2 tables, from the schema you've shown here I don't see that (unless that's the dID column). If you can modify the table structure for table_2 then you would need to add a new column that references the primary key from table_1 and when you set up the relationship specify that you want cascade deletes. This helps prevent orphan data by removing the additional details in related tables.

Comment: Simon dID is the common in the two tables ID is the Primary Key and both Tables.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL or ...? 
You would set dID in table_2 as the foreign key assuming it relates to table_1.ID. Then when you delete an ID in table_1 the database would delete any rows with that ID in table_2.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to mark records in table_1 as logically deleted though. As per balexandre's comment. To do this you would need to add a boolean (true / false) column to table_1 - call it IsDeleted and set a default of false, then when you do your delete you set it to true. This way means you will have to change any selects against the table so you add a WHERE IsDeleted = False (so you return only the undeleted items).

Answer (score 0):

OK, belxandre is completely correct; you shouldn't delete these records. You should have the ability to mark them Inactive or something. Having said that, you can create a SqlCommand that does the delete, add the necessary parameters to it, then call it on your DataAdapter:

```
SqlCommand delcomm = new SqlCommand();
delcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //I'd do it with an sp, up to you
delcomm.CommandText = "sp_delUser";
SqlParameter delParam = new SqlParameter("@dID", SqlDbType.Int);//I'm assuming this is the column you need and the right datatype
delcomm.Parameters.Add(delParam);
da.DeleteCommand = delcomm;
da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
da.Update(UserTable);//you'll need to set up a DataTable with the right data structure
UserTable.AcceptChanges();
```

This is totally off the top of my head; you may need to fiddle with this a bit, but it's generally what you need to do, if I understand your question. Having cascading deletes on your tables as suggested is also a good idea.

Comment: Ok ! its seems very logical and a sense able thing to do, to mark them inactive, can you enlighten me on that please

Comment: See balexandre's comment, above. You'll need to change your table structure